# jquery Button, Knockout.js and an ajax request

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-button

I am using knockout.js with jquery ui button.  I built a custom binding on the button which is below.  I am changing the text on the click item, but I also have additional click that submits an ajax request.  What is the best design pattern to set the text back to the original text once the request is complete.  I know I can do it manually or, pass the element being called to the method, but is there a more de-coupled way.

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="button: { text: 'login', pressed: 'authenticating...' }, click: function() { site.ajaxRequest(); }"></button>


ko.bindingHandlers.button = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

            var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            $(element).button({ label: binding.text }).click(function () {
                $(this).button({ label: binding.pressed });
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend binding the button to hardcoded text. Instead, I recommend binding the jQuery UI button to an observable and then updating that observable appropriately:

First snippet is a binding that can be used to update a jQuery UI button that I use. (psuedo code)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonText =
{
    init: function (element, valueAccessor)
    {
        ko.bindingHandlers.buttonText.update(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor)
    {
        var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).button({label: binding});
    }
};
```

Next, here is what your binding would look like. This assumes you have an observable on your model called textObservable;

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="button: {buttonText: textObservable, click: site.ajaxRequest"></button>
```

Finally, in your ajaxRequest method, before you make the AJAX request, you need to update textObservable to 'Authenticating'. In the **success handler** of the ajax call, you need to update textObservable to your initial value.

Comment: Makes sense.  But if I have more then one button on the page I would have to add an item for every button to my view model.  I guess I could do that but I would rather keep static ui display with the element but that is just me.  I will try it out and see if I like it.